# Pandas - Numeric Value Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do we select the columns which have numeric values of all the columns present in a data frame?

We can select the required columns by using the column name and then by slicing those columns from the data frame, but how do we extract those columns using the data type that is present in it

Comment: Would you please post the code that you've used to attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

let's imagine you already have a dataframe `df`

`df` with only numerical data is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_numeric = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```